# How to add chunkhash to dynamicaly imported chunks but not vendor

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

What I'm trying to do is generate a bundle with all the vendor scripts and then have multiple chunks based on dynamic imports.

The problem is that if I don't add the chunkname or hashname to the config all the chunks that are generated because of dynamic imports, don't get the cache busted.

I wanted to be able to just add chunkname or hashname to the chunk generated  but not the common/vendor one since I have other mechanism to break the cache on that file.

Is it possible?

Comment: After looking into the docs with more detail, with filename, because it accepts a function, would be possible to do this, but chunkname only accepts strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want to achieve.

```
optimization = {
    minimize: true,
    nodeEnv: 'production',
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vues: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](vue)/,
                name: 'vues',
                chunks: 'all'
            },
            others: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](axios|fastclick)/,
                name: 'others',
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
}
```